# Double cover ramified on a smooth conic of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $Z:=\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$,   $\pi: Y\to Z$ be a double cover ramified on a smooth conic $E\subset Z$. Why $Y\cong \mathbb{P}^{1}\times\mathbb{P}^{1}$?

First I try to find linear system on $\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{1}$ and write the map. I find $h^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{1},\mathcal{O}(2,0))=3$, so $|\mathcal{O}(2,0)|$ define a map to $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, but the map is actually $\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{1}\to \mathbb{P}^{1}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2}$. It is not $\pi$.

So I think the only way to get this is to write the expression of $\pi$: $$\mathbb{P}^{1}\times \mathbb{P}^{1} \to \mathbb{P}^{2}: ([x_{0}:y_{0}],[x_{1}:y_{1}])\to [x:y:z]$$
For example, if the equation $E$ is $xy-z^{2}=0$, then we  can write what $\pi$ is. But I failed. I do not know how to the such a map. I think it should not be hard. Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to prove a more general fact --- the double covering of a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ ramified over a smooth quadric $Q \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ (of dimension $n-1$) is a smooth quadric of dimension $n$.

Comment: @Sasha  I see. Basically , we can just project the smooth quadric surface to hyperplane, then we can prove that. But, I wonder, how we find it is ramified along quadric? I try $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, it seems if we just use coordinate, it is complicated.

Comment: One way is to **compute** the ramification locus (essentially, characterizing lines through the center of the projection which are tangent to the quadric). Another way, is to play with Riemann-Hurwitz formula. And I am sure there many other ways.